# Ajax Jquery Spring Post Method Not Working

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to use Post method in Ajax, but it is not working. It always return Full HTML Page Code.

```
@PostMapping("api/account/otp/phonenumber")
    @ResponseBody
    public String getOtpPhoneNumber() {
        return "Success!";
    }
```

```
$.ajax({
            type:"post",
            url:"/api/account/otp/phonenumber",
            success: function(result){
                console.log(result);
            }
        });
```

Bellow is response
[image]

But when i use get method, it properly give output.

```
   @GetMapping("api/account/otp/phonenumber")
    @ResponseBody
    public String getOtpPhoneNumber() {
        return "Success!";
    }
```

[image]

I am confused, what i am missing!

Comment: where is response of post?

Comment: I have shared the image of response, please check the image

Comment: Can you open html page & go to network page to check what error you see while using post? Specifically looking for any HTTP status code you can see in your error code.